# nested ifelse in mutate won't recognise is.na statement

Tags: r

I am trying to categorize some observations into whether one date column is before or after another date column in R.

data table:  merge_data

Two dates columns: case_plan_start_date, date_made

I want to categorize the observations with NA date into two categories: missing start date or missing legal date

I used the mutate and ifelse function like below, it seems to work for all of them except the 2nd line where it said is.na(CP_time). It seems to be the case whenever it I use mutate/ifelse, it won't recognize my second is. na statement.

It will categorize into "missing start date" but for those with missing NA legal date it won't categorize even into "unknown" and it just comes up as NA instead.

It will be great if anyone can find out a better way or correct way of doing this.

```
merge_data_t  <- merge_data %>%
  mutate(CP_time = lubridate::time_length(difftime(case_plan_start_date, date_made),"days"),

        flag_time_CP = ifelse(is.na(CP_time) & (is.na(case_plan_start_date) | case_plan_start_date == ""), "Missing start date", 
                        ifelse(is.na(CP_time), "Missing legal order",
                        ifelse(CP_time < 0, "before order date",
                        ifelse(CP_time == 0, "same date as order date",
                        ifelse(CP_time > 0, "after order date", "unknown")))))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with if_else, but does with case_when?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to use `case_when` here.

```
merge_data_t  <- merge_data %>%
  mutate(CP_time = lubridate::time_length(difftime(case_plan_start_date, date_made),"days"),

        flag_time_CP = case_when(
                          is.na(CP_time) & (is.na(case_plan_start_date) | case_plan_start_date == "") ~ "Missing start date", 
                          is.na(CP_time) ~ "Missing legal order",
                          CP_time < 0 ~ "before order date",
                          CP_time == 0 ~ "same date as order date",
                          CP_time > 0 ~ "after order date", "unknown"))
```